# Show $\det (A) \det(B)=\det(matrix)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given, $$A=
\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{1,1}&a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1}&a_{2,2} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$ B=
\left(\begin{matrix}
b_{1,1}&b_{1,2} \\
b_{2,1}&b_{2,2} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Show 
$$
\det\left(\begin{matrix}
A&0 \\
0&B \\
\end{matrix}\right)=\det(A)\det(B)
$$

I know how to solve the right side. But I wasn't sure about the left determinant. I tried to find out $\det(AB)$ where $AB$ is found by using matrix multiplication and I get

$$
\det\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}&a_{1,1}b_{1,2}+a_{1,2}b_{2,2}\\
a_{2,1}b_{1,1}+a_{2,2}b_{2,1}&a_{2,1}b_{1,2}+a_{2,2}b_{2,2} \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

and I don't think this is right as this doesn't equal to the right side

Comment: Expand on the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Using the usual method for determinants by the first column we have:

\begin{align*}
\det\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix} &=\begin{vmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 0 & 0 & b_{21} & b_{22}\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}\begin{vmatrix}a_{22} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 0 & b_{21} & b_{22}\end{vmatrix} - a_{21}\begin{vmatrix}a_{12} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 0 & b_{21} & b_{22}\end{vmatrix}\\
&=a_{11}a_{22}\begin{vmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{vmatrix}-a_{21}a_{12}\begin{vmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{vmatrix}\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12}\\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{vmatrix}\cdot (a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12})\\
&=\det(B)\cdot \det(A).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You can take a standard approach and just expand both sides of $\det (A)\det (B)=\det (AB)$ to see if the equation holds true.

Starting with the left side we have:
$$\begin{align}\det (A)\det (B)&=(a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{2,1}a_{1,2})(b_{1,1}b_{2,2}-b_{2,1}b_{1,2})\\&=a_{1,1}a_{2,2}b_{1,1}b_{2,2}-a_{1,1}a_{2,2}b_{2,1}b_{1,2}-b_{1,1}b_{2,2}a_{2,1}a_{1,2}+a_{2,1}a_{1,2}b_{1,2}b_{2,1}\end{align}$$
For the right side we have:
$$\begin{align}\det (AB)&=(a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1})(a_{2,1}b_{1,2}+a_{2,2}b_{2,2})-(a_{2,1}b_{1,1}+a_{2,2}b_{2,1})(a_{1,1}b_{1,2}+a_{1,2}b_{2,2})\\&=a_{1,1}b_{1,1}a_{2,1}b_{1,2}+a_{1,1}b_{1,1}a_{2,2}b_{2,2}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}a_{2,1}b_{1,2}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}a_{2,2}b_{2,2}-a_{2,1}b_{1,1}a_{1,1}b_{1,2}-a_{2,1}b_{1,1}a_{1,2}b_{2,2}-a_{2,2}b_{2,1}a_{1,1}b_{1,2}-a_{2,2}b_{2,1}a_{1,2}b_{2,2}\\&=a_{1,1}b_{1,1}a_{2,2}b_{2,2}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}a_{2,1}b_{1,2}-a_{2,1}b_{1,1}a_{1,2}b_{2,2}-a_{2,2}b_{2,1}a_{1,1}b_{1,2}\end{align}$$
We can now see that the two sides do equal (messy but it works).

Comment: That's correct, but you don't even have to expand the determinants. It's enough to notice that the matrix in the OP *is* actually $A B$.

Comment: @dxiv I took it as he/she is trying to show that $\det (A)\det (B)=\det (AB)$ without already assuming that fact about determinants.

Comment: That is possible, of course. Given the title of the question, however, I don't know that the OP did in fact realize that the $matrix$ is actually $A B$.

Comment: @dxiv That is a good point. I suppose if  they are able to use that property of determinants the question does just boil down to recognition that $matrix=AB$.